# How to fix ImportError: cannot import name _wrapper using slycot

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed the python package [slycot](https://github.com/jgoppert/Slycot) under anaconda on OS X using

```
conda install -c http://conda.binstar.org/cwrowley slycot
```

but then when I tried to use it by

```
import slycot
```

I got this error

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/pheon/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slycot/_wrapper.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/gcc/4.9/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/pheon/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slycot/_wrapper.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Am I missing something I should install?

I have libgfortran.3.dylib but it is installed under

/usr/local/lib/gcc/5

Do I have to link something?

UPDATE:

I created a new conda environment and install slycot into that. I had to install a gcc too, so something was probably wrong with the linking.

Having done that, I still got the ImportError. So I tried installing from source again. That produced a long log of fortran output, so it must have been doing something different this time.

However, I still get the ImportError.

./lib/libgfortran.3.dylib is installed under the env.

and

```
otool -L /Users/pheon/anaconda/envs/snowflakes/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/slycot/_wrapper.so
```

gives

```
/Users/pheon/anaconda/envs/snowflakes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slycot/_wrapper.so:
    liblapack.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/./libgfortran.3.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 955.0.0)
    /Users/acurtis/anaconda/envs/snowflakes/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/./libquadmath.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1225.1.1)
```

and

```
>>>import slycot
```

still gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "slycot/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .analysis import ab01nd,ab05md,ab05nd,ab07nd,ab08nd, ab09ad, \
  File "slycot/analysis.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import _wrapper
ImportError: cannot import name _wrapper
```

Could it be something to do with that "@rpath". I didn't see that before?

Comment: Is there any output during the conda installation? (Does conda have a --verbose option?)

Comment: Nothing that looked like a warning or error. It installed lapack-3.5.0 and slycot-0.2.0.

Comment: But does it attempt to install a wheel?

Comment: Please verify that `otool -L /Users/pheon/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slycot/_wrapper.so` does show an incorrect path for libgfortran.3.dylib.

Comment: That command gives :
  /usr/local/lib/gcc/4.9/libgfortran.3.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
which is the incorrect path.

Comment: It may be worth installing, and in particular building, the package from source. That should either pick up the correct gfortran library, or show you more clearly what's going wrong. Or find a way to use conda with (multiple) verbose options when (re)installing the package and see what exactly it does: not showing a warning or error doesn't mean conda does everything correctly.

Comment: Alternatively, the easy way out might be to use a symlink. But that only bypasses the problem, it doesn't solve it (and thus you may end up with a similar problem later on).

Comment: I installed from source. Now tool says _wrapper.so is linked tov/usr/local/lib/gcc/5/libgfortran.3.dylib, which exists but I still get an ImportError

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91674/discussion-between-pheon-and-evert).

Comment: Did you ever work out a solution to this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I turns out slicot uses the library from gcc 4.9. The solution is to install gcc 4.9. I did this using homebrew

```
brew install gcc49
```

Now everything works fine.